# array1.filter is not a function ng-tags-input

Tags: javascript, angularjs, autocomplete, angularjs-filter, ng-tags-input

i'm using the auto-complete in tags-input but when i start writing i get this error: array1.filter is not a function. This is my angular call

```
$scope.loadTags = function(query) {
            var searchPeople = $scope.baseUrl + "&searchString=";
            return $http.get(searchPeople + query, {

            }).success(function (data) {
                $scope.people = data.data.data;
                console.log($scope.people);
            }).error(function (data){
                console.log("Error");
            });
        };
```

moreover i don't know how to retrieve a value from, in my case $scope.people json that is something like:

```
{
   "id": 17,
   "cod": "gg117",
   "name": "Alex"
}
```

i know that i need a custom template but as long as i get the error i can't do it. By the way the template is this one but i don't know if it's correct

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="my-custom-template">
   <div class="left-panel">
        <img ng-src="./img/avatar.jpeg" />
   </div>
   <div class="right-panel">
        <span ng-bind-html="$highlight($getDisplayText())"></span>
        <span>({{people.name}})</span>
  </div>
</script>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error using ngTagInput : TypeError: a.filter is not a function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38601519/error-using-ngtaginput-typeerror-a-filter-is-not-a-function)

Answer (score 4):

you need to pass a promise, with data of the format

```
{
"data":[{'text':'tag1'}, {'text', 'tag1'}]
}
```