# Error using ngTagInput : TypeError: a.filter is not a function

Tags: ng-tags-input

I am trying to use ngTagInput with autocomplete but getting following Error:

```
angular.min.js:117 TypeError: a.filter is not a function
at d (ng-tags-input.min.js:1)
at ng-tags-input.min.js:1
at angular.min.js:130
at n.$eval (angular.min.js:144)
at n.$digest (angular.min.js:142)
at n.$apply (angular.min.js:145)
at l (angular.min.js:97)
at H (angular.min.js:101)
at XMLHttpRequest.u.onload (angular.min.js:102)
```

**HTML**

```
<tags-input ng-model="selectedList">
  <auto-complete source="getData($query)"></auto-complete>
</tags-input>
```

**Javascript**

```
$scope.getData = function(query) { 
  var request = {
    // GET request is defined here
  };

  return $http(request).success(function(response, status) {
    var defer = $q.defer();
    defer.resolve([
      { 'text': 'just' },
      { 'text': 'some' },
      { 'text': 'cool' },
      { 'text': 'tags' }
    ]);
    return defer.promise;
  });
};
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/vKvNCcSwuzeGv65poVEB?p=preview)

Comment: Could you provide a Plunker showing your problem? You can use [this template](http://plnkr.co/edit/tpl:93P2qxOjYmlcYSqDmo39).

Comment: @MichaelBenford : Hey, I updated the plunker with the problem.

1. First ngtagInput  is the component that you provided..nothing changed
2. Second ngtagInput which is working with promise but without http get call.
3. Third is the actual problem where I am using http get with promise.
In my case, URL is the url for the backend REST service . I am getting into sucess block, getting the data array but when it comes to "return $defer.promise" it fails with the Error I mentioned in the problem statement

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/vKvNCcSwuzeGv65poVEB?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the `success` method, that isn't chainable, i.e. it ignores return values, so the `getData` function is, in fact, returning the `$http` promise directly, which according to your Plunker, happens to resolve into an undetermined value, hence the `filter is not a function` error, since the `autoComplete` directive expects an array.

You should use `then` instead of `success` (you also don't need to create a new promise in order to return a value from inside another promise):

```
$scope.getData = function(query) { 
  ...
  return $http(request).then(function(response, status) {
    return [
      { 'text': 'just' },
      { 'text': 'some' },
      { 'text': 'cool' },
      { 'text': 'tags' }
   ];
  });
}
```

[Updated Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/4pIbNXrAfp1UMIzy8r89?p=preview)

That'll work, but it doesn't make much sense because it issues a request and then discards its response. If you don't need to handle the response, you can simply return the http promise directly (assuming the response structure is valid for the directive):

```
$scope.getData = function(query) { 
  ...
  return $http(request);
};
```

Finally, both `success` and `error` methods [have been deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35331339/1349152). You should always use `then` instead.

Comment: Thats Awesome! it worked.. I was using success instead of then.. cool Thanks @Michael

Comment: Is there any way, I can change color of a tag entered by user which is not a part of suggestion list? i.e. as a warning to user that he is going to add unknown tag(in red?)

Comment: @user3709671 You should [create](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) another question for that.

Comment: sure..I will do that :) Here is the link for the question

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38645139/dynamic-coloring-tags-in-ngtaginput